# Как в twig вывести активный элементы первым?

Tags: html, twig, symfony3

Имеем массив объектов, которые нужно вывести

```
{% for item in items %}
  <li></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Также элемент может быть активным

```
{% for item in items %}
  <li class="{% if smth == smth2 %}active{% endif %}"></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Так как элементом может быть много, а блок ограничен по высоте, то требуется внутренний скролл, но активный элемент может потеряться в этой портянке, так что требуется вывести его первым элементом

```
{% for item in items %}
{% if smth == smth2 %}
   {% if loop.index == 1 %}
      <li class="active"></li>
   {% endif %}
{% else %}
  <li></li>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Это все к чему я пришел, но не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите это сделать именно в шаблоне (не используя сортировку в контроллере), то проще всего пройти два раза по массиву `items`:

```
<!-- сначала выводим только активные --> 
{% for item in items %}
  {% if smth == smth2 %}
    <li class="active"></li>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

<!-- а потом всё остальное -->
{% for item in items %}
  {% if smth != smth2 %}
    <li></li>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```